# Win Form Application run under Operating System?

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system

I make and run Windows form application in VS. Then I close the VS (not running win form application). But still my Windows form application was running.

Does this mean that Windows form Application runs under operating system ?

Comment: was the VS still debugging your winform app when you closed it ?

Comment: @Kapoor 1) I didn't insert any break point 2) I just debug/run my application and then close the VS.

Comment: I have added my response, do let me know if I answered your point or if there is some more clarification which i may provide

Answer (score 1):

basically when you create a win form application in visual studio, the first time you run it, it creates an executable (.exe) file in its bin folder. so even though when you close visual studio it will keep running.

> (but when you run it in debug mode, the moment you close the VS, your
>   win form application will also be closed)

but one thing any program or process that runs in your machine is managed by operating system, like allocating memory resources etc...

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I have to put this as an answer since I need to place some image -

Closing VS will close the application only when its being debugged and you have started the app using VS

Being debugged - (you see a Running on top left)

[image]

- This is true for both - Current project or an external system

[image]

However, if you are debugging an application by Debug -> Attach to process. 
Closing VS will not kill the applicaiton although you can debug it.

Comment: _“I have to put this as an answer since I need to place some image”_ No, you can simply upload the image using the answer form, then copy the generated image link to the comments.

Comment: @Xufox: thanks for the idea, I'm new here and I had never tried it